# search box result == Json result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I have a Node.js server that reads a JSON file and there are a lot of information in it. One of them is ID of a person, I have a search box in my HTML page I wanna right a jquery method(ajax required) for the client side to find if the ID that the user put in the search box is the same as the ID in JSON, if it is I wanna return some information about that person, let's say name and username of the user.

Note: I am 100% sure that my server.js file works.

Please help me, I am kind of a newbie in Jquery.

I have so far;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_of_the_search_box_button").click(function (any_function_variable_name) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/url_of_the_related_server_side',
      dataType: 'json'
      })
          .done(function(data){
              console.log(data);
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));

              data.forEach(function (any_function_variable_name) {

                if(any_function_variable_name.search_box_ID == any_function_variable_name.name_in_the_JSON_file_for_one_of_the_searched_ID){

                    $userElement = $("<li>").html("<strong>ID: </strong>" + any_function_variable_name.id); //id is defined in JSON and I was able to use in another part of the jquery
                    $userBlock = $("<ul>")
                        .append(
                            $("<li>").html("<strong>Name: </strong>" + any_function_variable_name.name) //name of the user
                        )
                        .append(
                            $userElement
                        )
                        .append(
                            $("<li>").html("<strong>User User Name: </strong>" + any_function_variable_name.userName)
                        );
                                                                  $any_function_variable_nameBlock.insertAfter("#search");
            }
            });
    });})})
```

Note: I don't know if I could close the brackets right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide structure of your json file? Sample data will help...

Comment: [{...    
"id" : 37595960858,
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"user": {
 "id": 2384451,
 "id_str": "238678",
 "name": "Doga I",
 "screen_name": "IDoga",
... 

"id" : 65739068412,
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"user": {
 "id": 2878009,
 "id_str": "235678",
 "name": "Jon Doe",
 "user_name": "JD",
...
}]

The id that user writes in the search box should match with the one that is not in the user.

Comment: P.S: I don't use express

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question properly, `[
  {
    "id": 37595960858,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
      "id": 2384451,
      "id_str": "238678",
      "name": "Doga I",
      "screen_name": "IDoga"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 65739068412,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
      "id": 2878009,
      "id_str": "235678",
      "name": "Jon Doe",
      "user_name": "JD"
    }
  }
]` is your structure and you want to match to  `{ id: ...}` and not `{ user: { id: ...} }` ... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like as shown below ...

Instead of making an ajax call, I wrote with static data as below ...

> HTML

```
<input id="searchBox" type="text" />
<button id="id_of_the_search_box_button">
Search
</button>

<ul>

</ul>
```

> JS

```
var data = [
  {
    "id": 37595960858,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
      "id": 2384451,
      "id_str": "238678",
      "name": "Doga I",
      "screen_name": "IDoga"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 65739068412,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
      "id": 2878009,
      "id_str": "235678",
      "name": "Jon Doe",
      "user_name": "JD"
    }
  }
];


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_of_the_search_box_button").click(function (any_function_variable_name) {

    var searchText = parseInt($('#searchBox').val());


    data.forEach(function (any_function_variable_name) {

      if(any_function_variable_name.id === searchText){

        $("ul")
            .append('<li> <strong>ID: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.id)
            .append('<li> <strong>User Name: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.user_name)
            .append('<li> <strong>Name: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.name)
            .append('<li> <strong>Screen Name: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.screen_name);

      } //End if

    }); //End forEach

  });
});
```

which makes your ajax call like this ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_of_the_search_box_button").click(function (any_function_variable_name) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/url_of_the_related_server_side',
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data){


      var searchText = parseInt($('#searchBox').val());


      data.forEach(function (any_function_variable_name) {

        if(any_function_variable_name.id === searchText){

          $("ul")
            .append('<li> <strong>ID: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.id)
            .append('<li> <strong>User Name: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.user_name)
            .append('<li> <strong>Name: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.name)
            .append('<li> <strong>Screen Name: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.user.screen_name);

        } //End if

      }); //End forEach



    });
  });
});
```

Following is the fiddler

https://jsfiddle.net/rrtbz4bo/7/

Enter `37595960858` in search box and hit search.

> UPDATE: call the /find/id?id=... api directly if it returns data like

```
{
    "id": 37595960858,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
      "id": 2384451,
      "id_str": "238678",
      "name": "Doga I",
      "screen_name": "IDoga"
    }
  }
```

Then following should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_of_the_search_box_button").click(function (any_function_variable_name) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      //Or whatever your URL structure is
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5230/find/id?Id=' + $('#searchBox').val(),
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data){
      $("ul")
      .append('<li> <strong>ID: </strong>' + data.user.id)
      .append('<li> <strong>User Name: </strong>' + data.user.user_name)
      .append('<li> <strong>Name: </strong>' + data.user.name)
      .append('<li> <strong>Screen Name: </strong>' + data.user.screen_name);
    });
  });
});
```

If this doesn't work, post a fiddler and i'll try and make it work.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: It didn't work, I think the problem is bigger than I think. Thanks for trying.
If you don't mind can you write a general structure because when I use 127.0.0.1:5230/find/id?... and write the write id instead ... I am seeing the right answer on terminal/console(I have a console.log()). The problem is that my jquery ajax should see the search box value compare that value with the values in JSON and if they match they need to return that person's information.
Thanks once again

Comment: Then remove the forEach loop, and set your ajax url like the....  url: '
http://127.0.0.1:5230/find/id?Id=' + $('#searchBox').val()      I.e. Directly call the api with id.

Comment: You can also directly use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ instead of $.post if you want

Comment: Can I ask another question to you?

Comment: Sure... If it's not related you can post another question as well. :)

Comment: Same project but different question. I am asking a new one under why am I getting commas ? :)

Comment: I am so close to the answer but I am getting undefined as data output with the updated code, there is no error on the console. From the server side data comes as array of object. Further help?